# ¿Problemas al usar la libreria ShapeOfView android Studio?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, librería

Buen día comunidad estoy haciendo una Activity en Android Studio y necesito usar la liberia ShapeOfView para dar diseño a una parte pero al momento de ejecutar la aplicacion me arroja este error:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Estoy usando la siguiente implemntacion de libreiria: implementation 'io.github.florent37:shapeofview:1.4.7'

Intente usar la version 1.3.2 pero tampo me funciono.

Comment: Tu problema realmente no es ese,  esta en tu proyecto.

Comment: Al fin lo pude resolver al momento de usar la libreria shapeofview la siguiente linea de código no funciona   app:shape_arc_cropDirection="outside" y es necesario quitarla para que funcione

Answer (score 0):

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Solo para futuras referencias a los que tengan este error nuevamente. En efecto, se debe de eliminar la siguiente línea si la tienen agregada en su componente.